# Remove parentheses after author in beamer document

Tags: beamer

the following copy&paste code results in showing "short name ()" in the left box of the navigation bar.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title[short title]{long title}
\author[short name]{long name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Not here, no ()'s in sight. Which version are you using?

Comment: You are definitly using old version - there is a workaround, but much better idea is use version 3.24 and newer. After that, the () will show only if you specify `\institute`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem could easily be solved by an update of the TeX installation.